# Dynamically create layout (similar to listview)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create what is basically a list view but without it being a ListView.

So I have a ListView right now that pulls up a layout with a CardView, TextView, etc. However I need to create multiple lists but listviews wrap the content up and makes me scroll inside the view - I don't want this. I want to be able to see the entire list and scroll in the main view.

How can I just add the layout with the CardView, instead of displaying it as a ListView? Would be a lot easier if I could attach an adapter to a Linear Layout or something.

Edit: I know I could add it all in the XML, but it seems like it'd get very bad looking in the xml code.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're looking to accomplish. By "makes me scroll inside the view", do you mean you're currently nesting ListViews? By "multiple lists" do you mean all items in List 1, then all items in List 2, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it makes me scroll inside the listview. So I'll have a list for name, then another for places, but the last list doesn't go out the screen it wraps itself up and creates its own scroll. I'd like to be able to scroll the entire screen with the contents of every list always being expanded.

I tried using a ScrollView, but, well... that just goes horribly wrong. I could just make one big list, but then how would I handle different categories? Maybe that's the easier way and I'm making it too complicated haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView (and RecyclerView) do a *ton* of non-trivial things that are very difficult to independently implement with your own homemade alternative. Fortunately, there are many third-party solutions that address your particular problem. A good choice is [CWAC's MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge). It's essentially a wrapper of sub-adapters.

To handle the section headers, you can either make the first item of each sub-adapter a header item (styled accordingly). Or use `MergeAdapter's` `addView()` method to add a "header" view before each `addAdapter()` call.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this now, seems like it does exactly what I want.

Comment: That absolutely did it! Thanks again Krylez!